# Ошибка при запуске Selenium python

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver

код:

```python
from selenium.webdriver.chrome import webdriver

url="https://metanit.com/"
browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
browser.get(url)
```

при запуске выдаёт ошибку:

```console
browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver' has no attribute 'Chrome'
```

Comment: Импорт неправильный. Но ты держи нас и дальше в курсе

Comment: Могу я узнать правильный импорт)?

Comment: да, можете. В интернете много примеров.

Comment: `from selenium import webdriver; bro=webdriver.Chrome()`

Answer (score 0):

У Вас неправильный импорт. Также заметил что Вы указываете путь до драйвера.
Вместо полного пути на драйвер используйте лучше библиотеку `webdriver-manager`

устанавливается следующей командой:

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

Импортируется следующим образом:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
```

Далее объявляем переменную, в которой будет драйвер:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
```

После этого можно переходить по ссылкам

```
url="https://metanit.com/"
driver.get(url)
```